# problema para hacer un deploy en render donde el login está conectado a una base de datos MySql

Tags: python, mysql, login, fastapi

Tengo un problema para lograr que se me ejecute el login en un deploy de render. El login tiene conexión a un Schema simple de MySQL. La cuestión es que cuando lo ejecuto localmente no hay problema, funciona pero cuando intento hacerlo en render no funciona, es decir logra el deploy pero cuando voy hacer click en login colocando las credenciales me tira error interno 500. He probado varias posibles soluciones y aún así persiste el error: dejo un pedazo del codigo del login

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Response, Depends, HTTPException
from tests2 import *
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse, FileResponse, HTMLResponse, JSONResponse
from fastapi import Response, Depends, HTTPException, FastAPI, Form
from fastapi.security import HTTPBasic, HTTPBasicCredentials
import pandas as pd
import os
import pymysql
from starlette import responses

app = FastAPI()
security = HTTPBasic()

db_host = os.getenv("DB_HOST")
db_port = int(os.getenv("DB_PORT"))
db_user = os.getenv("DB_USER")
db_password = os.getenv("DB_PASSWORD")
db_name = os.getenv("DB_NAME")


@app.get("/")
def home():
    html = leer_html('home.html')
    return responses.HTMLResponse(content=html, status_code=200)

sessions = {}

@app.post("/login")
async def login(credentials: HTTPBasicCredentials = Depends(security)):
    # Estableciendo conexión con la base de datos
    conexion = pymysql.connect(
        host=db_host,
        port=db_port,
        user=db_user,
        password=db_password,
        database=db_name
    )
    cursor = conexion.cursor()

    query = 'SELECT * FROM USUARIOS'
    cursor.execute(query)

    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, conexion)

    conexion.commit()
    conexion.close()

    username = credentials.username
    password = credentials.password

    # Chequeo de usuario y contraseña válido
    if username in df['usuario'].values and password == df.loc[df['usuario'] == username, 'contraseña'].values[0]:
        sessions[username] = True
        return {"Message": "Login successful"}
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Incorrect username or password")
```

A su vez coloco en las environment variables en render los valores correspondientes a DB_HOST, DB_USER y así sucesivamente. Al ejecutarlo de manera local y funcionar, no es una cuestión de dichos valores, si no de la conexión entre MySQL y render.
La base de datos está activa, he desactivado el firewall, le he garantizado todos los permisos y otras cuestiones más y aún sigue igual